# how can call an action in specific text selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My idea is call an action just when the  is 'yes' but i dont want to call and action when is not. Example. in the next code each id is a photo (i can see that every photo have diferent Id) . Inside this one there are a < Spam> that contain a Button and an  that contain text()='yes'or'no'. i want to click the button but just in photos that contain 'yes' in < a>.

```
<div>
  <div>
     <div id="213142143fcfa5238352110">
        <div>
             <spam>
             </spam>
             <a>
                'yes'
             </a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="5da16123cfcfa5238352160">
        <div>
             <spam>
             </spam>
             <a>
                'no'
             </a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="y6565345225afasdas521220">
        <div>
             <spam>
             </spam>
             <a>
                'no'
             </a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="00943324fa52323432432405">
        <div>
             <spam>
             </spam>
             <a>
                'yes'
             </a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for example you can see in the next photo. I want to take the xpath from the < div> that have inside < a> 'Publicidad'(there are one that have it and the other no), after that with the xpath make click in the < div> inside to this < div> (where say 'click here'). I use python and selenium. Thanks

[image]

Comment: duplicate ? mate , reed the bought post before to comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a_link = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
            for a in a_link:
                try:
                    if a.text == "yes":
                        a.click()
                except:
                    print("NO in a tag")
```

Edited:

```
 columns = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._5jmm._5pat._3lb4.f_3naoxe8gn")
                for column in columns:
                    #place the class in the css selector its not visible
                    a_link = column.find_element_by_css_selector("CLASS")
                    try:
                        if a.text == "yes":
                            #place the class of the div you want to click
                            button = column.find_element_by_css_selector("CLASS")
                            button.click()
                    except:
                        print("NO in a tag")
```

Comment: how are you ? your code is okay but just for look the < a> that contains 'yes' or no.... but i dont want to make click in < a> , as i have wrote before , i wan to click in < SPAM> not in < a> (this one is just to find the photo that have 'yes or 'no' , but after that i want to click in Spam just in the photos with yes)

Comment: Hey i'm fine thank you. How are you doing?
Please have a look at the https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html
Hope it will help.

Comment: i upload a photo... look the photo maybe i can explain better what i want

Comment: @emanuellemos Please take a look since the classes is not visible you have to place the classes inside the css selector and let me know.

Comment: thanks , really ... amazing answer. We need more people like you in this foro

Answer (score 0):

To get `spam` inside `div` with child `a` and specific text, use below XPATH:

1. `//a[contains(.,'yes')]/ancestor::div[@id][1]//spam`
2. `//a[contains(.,'yes')]/preceding-sibling::spam`
3. `//div[@id and .//a[contains(.,'yes')]]//spam`

Comment: i upload a photo... look the photo maybe i can explain better what i want